# Keep getting Undefined index error

Tags: php, html

I am literarily driving myself nuts with this problem.

I have this code in PHP:

```
 private function searchpage($data) {

  $file = @file_get_contents("./assets/template/search.html");
  $content = "";
  $pages = "";

 foreach ($data as $keys) {
 //var_dump($keys); This gives the correct information,I will show the    
 output later on.

        $content = str_replace("[PHOTO]",$keys['photo'], $file);
        $content = str_replace("[NAME]",$keys['name'], $content);
        $pages .= $content;
  }
 return $pages;
}
```

The var_dump from $keys looks like this

```
  array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["_id"]=> string(1) "2" ["_user"]=>    
  string(1) "1" ["_short"]=> string(4) "test" ["_long"]=> string(9)   
  "test long" ["name"]=> string(4) "test" ["_dat"]=> string(10) "2017-  
   08-29" ["photo"]=> string(92) "https://s-media-cache-     
   "}
```

as you can see, I use the correct name tags.

The STR_REPLACE doesn't work though. I keep getting this error:

```
Undefined index: name in     
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/lib/_layout.php on line 144
Undefined index: photo in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/lib/_layout.php on line 145
```

The strange thing is: I do EXACTLY the same thing on a different HTML page, and there it works perfectly.

I have no clue what's wrong with this code. 
I do request the function. The data I give to the function is correct. It does open the correct HTML page. The only thing which isn't correct is the str_replace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: I've seen that one, but haven"t found the solution for my problem.

Comment: Try replacing `$content = str_replace("[PHOTO]",$keys['photo'], $file);
        $content = str_replace("[NAME]",$keys['name'], $content);` with `$content = str_replace("[PHOTO]",$keys[0]['photo'], $file);
        $content = str_replace("[NAME]",$keys[0]['name'], $content);`. The `var_dump` shows that `$keys` holds an array of data.

Comment: `$keys[0]['name']` try this way

Comment: Don't but answers in comments, please. If it is good enough to answer here, it is good enough to make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var_dump` says that `$keys` holds an `array` of data. Thus, in PHP, as you may know, if you are trying to access an array variable, you must specify the index also.

Thus, it should be `$keys[0]['photo']` instead of `$keys['photo']`. Similarly, it should be `$keys[0]['name']` instead of `$keys['name']`.

Please replace

```
    $content = str_replace("[PHOTO]",$keys['photo'], $file);
    $content = str_replace("[NAME]",$keys['name'], $content);
```

with

```
    $content = str_replace("[PHOTO]",$keys[0]['photo'], $file);
    $content = str_replace("[NAME]",$keys[0]['name'], $content);
```